# save sqlite3 file of my App

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sqlite, ipod

I'm new with dealing with the .sqlite3 in iphone, I created a sqlite3 file in

```
/Users/myLab/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/308C4355-D8EE-4524-A7F9-638DEB68B298/Documents/file.sqlite3
```

and I inserted the tables into it using Terminal.app and everything works ok with my app.

but when I moved this application to another device, opened by xcode and trying to run it, I discovered that my tables are not found in this .sqlite3 file in another device.

how can I save my tables in .sqlite3 file??

Comment: how did you **Move** the application to another device?  are you talking about installing it on an iPhone, for example?  are you talking about copying it to another Mac?

Comment: yes I mean copying it to another Mac device.

Comment: did you copy the entire `/Users/myLab/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/308C4355-D8EE-4524-A7F9-638DEB68B298/` folder to the other Mac?  or copy just the `Documents` subdirectory? or just the file.sqlite3 file?

Comment: No I copied the folder from the Documents (the folder that the Xcode created when I created a new App)

Comment: Can you run `ls -alt` in the `Documents` folder of both machines, and verify that the contents, and sizes of the files are/were the same, right after you did the copy?

Comment: sorry I'm new in Mac , so how can do ls -alt, and how will it solve my problem ??

Comment: you run Terminal.app to get yourself a command line.  then you change directory to the Documents folder, like this: `cd /Users/myLab/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/308C4355-D8EE-4524-A7F9-638DEB68B298/Documents/`.  Then, once you're there, you type `ls -alt` and get a listing of all the files in that directory, with their sizes.  This won't fix your problem.  I'm trying to determine if something is missing (didn't get copied over).

Comment: I did that and this is what I got: drwxr-xr-x  4 dt4it  staff    136 Sep  1 11:12 .
-rw-r--r--  1 dt4it  staff  49152 Sep  1 11:12 ebook.sqlite3
drwxr-xr-x  7 dt4it  staff    238 Aug 29 14:16 ..
-rw-r--r--@ 1 dt4it  staff   6148 Aug 29 14:16 .DS_Store

Comment: Ok, that was on one computer.  Which was that?  The first, or the second one?  And how about the same command run on the other?  Also, I noticed that in that listing, the file is called `ebook.sqlite3`.  In the question, you called it `file.sqlite3`. Were you just using psuedocode, or is there a mismatch in your filenames?

Comment: yes, It is the same file but I changed the name here to be public, and this is in the first device

Comment: So, your ebook.sqlite3 file has 49152 bytes of data.  Run the `ls -alt` command on the second computer, and see if the file sizes match.

Comment: it tells me that it is 15456 bytes

Comment: so, it looks like something is missing.  maybe double-check your copy.  try it again, and then rerun the app on the second computer.

Comment: how to double-check your copy ??

Comment: just copy it again.  those two files should be the same, right?  maybe you copied the file, and **then** added to tables to the original one?  or maybe something else failed when you transferred the file between machines.

Answer (score 0):

Whereas this much info is adiquate to answer you question though i am providing some checkmarks to check for:

1. Do you have file.sqlite3 in your app resource folder?
2. Do you have that given table in that resource file.sqlite3 file?
3. Have you made any changes to the file.sqlite3 placed in the resource folder while app is running? if yes then try deleting that file.sqlite3 from the resource and add again to the resources.

All these checkpoints may make your app work well.

BestLuck..